# no reference to Module.parameters() after using more than once

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a class that inherits from torch.nn.Module,

now when I do this code:

```
d = net.parameters()
print(len(list(d)))
print(len(list(d)))
print(len(list(d)))
```

the output is:

```
10
0
0
```

**So I have reference to the net.parameters() only once**, whys that?

Then it apparently disappear..
I got this error while trying to make my own Optimizer, so I pass this net.parameters() as a parameter to my new class, and apparently I couldn't use it because of that odd situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working as expected. `Module.parameters()` returns an iterator, more specifically, a Python generator. One thing about them is that you cannot rewind a generator. So, in the first `list(d)` call, you are actually "consuming" all the generator. Then, if you try to do that again, it will be empty.

If you're wondering, the `.parameters()` implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7572501d408583a06b687cb3f04e4a020c6fb408/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L854-L876), and it is very simple:

```py
def parameters(self, recurse=True):
    for name, param in self.named_parameters(recurse=recurse):
        yield param
```

Perhaps it is easier to wrap your mind around it with this toy example:

```py
def g():
    for x in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        yield x

d = g()
print(list(d))  # prints: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(d))  # prints: []
```